# Java Hamcrest : Collection contains item of type

Tags: java, unit-testing, hamcrest

I'd like to assert that `List<Achievement>` contains a member of type `TestAchievement`.

Here's my assertion:

```
List<Achievement> achievements; // Populated elsewhere
assertThat(achievements,hasItem(isA(TestAchievement.class)));
```

This doesn't compile, reporting the error:

> The method assertThat(T, Matcher)
>   in the type Assert is not applicable
>   for the arguments (List,
>   Matcher<Iterable<TestAchievement>>)

What's the correct syntax for this type of assertion using Hamcrest?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Thanks for all the help.

The posts here suggested it was a defect with Hamcrest, so I headed over to the hacmrest site to register a bug, whien I discovered that the mvn / ivy dependency declaration I was using was out-of-date, giving me an old version of Hamcrest.

This bug exists with 1.1, which is the latest if declared using

```
<dependency org="org.hamcrest" name="hamcrest-all" rev="1.1">
```

However, the correct depedency declaration is:

```
<dependency org="org.hamcrest" name="hamcrest-library" rev="1.3.RC2"/>
```

Updating to this solved the issue.  The syntax used in my test is:

```
 assertThat(achievements, hasItem(isA(TestAchievement.class)));
```

Comment: I spent nearly a week of headbanging once on this very same problem of a buggy declaration in the hamcrest library code before I finally stumbled on the fixed updated version.  Just nuts! Things should not be this complicated.

Answer (score 9):

There is a [bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7034548) in Java 6 that relates to this.

This code will throw various errors such as "cannot find symbol..."

```
assertThat(achievements, hasItem(isA(TestAchievement.class)));
```

The work around for this is to declare the matcher as a variable and then reference that variable. It is important to note that the type of the variable, specifically the generics section, is very important for this to work.

```
Matcher<Iterable<? super TestAchievement>> matcher = hasItem(isA(TestAchievement.class));
assertThat(achievements, matcher);
```

Interestingly if you use `instanceOf()` instead of `isA()` you once again run into issue. (although if you ignore the warnings this might just work for you anyway.) Expanding on the previous fix you can use:

```
Matcher<TestAchievement> itemMatcher = Matchers.instanceOf(TestAchievement.class);
Matcher<Iterable<? super TestAchievement>> matcher = hasItem(itemMatcher);
assertThat(achievements, matcher);
```

Comment: I typically add the comment `// work around for Java 6 Bug: http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7034548` whenever this comes up.

Answer (score 3):

```
assertThat(achievements, hasItem(
    IsInstanceOf.<Achievement>instanceOf(TestAchievement.class)));
```

Comment: That line doesn't compile. Here's the error message: `The method instanceOf(Class<?>) of type IsInstanceOf is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <Achievement>`

Comment: @limc It's generic in the code at the trunk: http://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/source/browse/trunk/hamcrest-java/hamcrest-core/src/main/java/org/hamcrest/core/IsInstanceOf.java

Answer (score 3):

I've been battling with this for a while, none of the approaches here really had the expected result. Out of pure despair I tried converting to an array to see if that made a difference:

```
List<Object> listOfThings = (List) someService.findThings(); // your business logic here
Object[] arrayOfThings  = listOfThings.toArray(new Object[listOfThings.size()]);

assertThat(arrayOfThings, hasItemInArray(instanceOf(SpecialThing.class)));
```

And it did make a difference. Now my test works flawlessly. The one line of copy-to-array seems to be a reasonable trade-off to save a lot of hassle.

Comment: If you want to avoid using primitive arrays see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981586/java-hamcrest-collection-contains-item-of-type/20751480#20751480). (You will still have the one extra line though.)

Answer (score 2):

I have been futzing around with this for awhile, and it seems like the only way I know is to convert `List<Achievement>` to `List<Object>`. The problem is `CoreMatchers.instanceOf()` returns `Matcher<Object>`.

With that modification, I'm able to get this to work:-

```
List<Object> achievements = new ArrayList<Object>();
achievements.add(new Achievement());
achievements.add(new TestAchievement());
assertThat(achievements, hasItem(instanceOf(TestAchievement.class)));
```

Answer (score 2):

From http://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/source/browse/trunk/hamcrest-java/hamcrest-core/src/main/java/org/hamcrest/MatcherAssert.java the signature is

```
assertThat(T actual, Matcher<? super T> matcher)
```

so the problem is that your matcher is a `Matcher<TestAchievement>`, not a matcher that works for any instance of a super-class or interface of achievement.

It looks like the `instanceOf` matcher just has a buggy type bound.
You can work around that bug by doing something like

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
Matcher/*no_param*/ isATestAchievement = instanceOf(TestAchievement.class);
assertThat(..., isATestAchievement);
```

Comment: This is a good example. Works for me but only on hamcrest 1.1. Upgrading to 1.2 or 1.3.0RC0 will give me n error.

Comment: The error (for 1.2) stacktrace:

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hamcrest.Matcher.describeMismatch(Ljava/lang/Object;Lorg/hamcrest/Description;)V
 at org.hamcrest.core.IsCollectionContaining.matchesSafely(IsCollectionContaining.java:31)
 at org.hamcrest.core.IsCollectionContaining.matchesSafely(IsCollectionContaining.java:14)
 at org.hamcrest.TypeSafeDiagnosingMatcher.matches(TypeSafeDiagnosingMatcher.java:54)
 at org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat(MatcherAssert.java:12)
 at org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat(MatcherAssert.java:8)

Comment: @JesperRønn-Jensen See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981586/java-hamcrest-collection-contains-item-of-type/20751480#20751480). This works with hamcrest 1.1 and 1.3.

Answer (score 2):

Actuall it does not work for a little bit more complex Matcher, even using latest release.

```
assertThat(result.getAnswers(),
            Matchers.hasItem(Matchers.hasProperty("content")));
```

It will not work, you will get a:

> The method assertThat(T, Matcher) in the type Assert is not applicable for the arguments (Set, Matcher>)

You can solve it by converting it to an array :

```
assertThat(result.getAnswers().toArray(), hasItemInArray(Matchers.hasProperty("content", equalTo("<h4>new comment</h4>"))));
```